# Min query Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a table named PriceChange. It has the following colums: Sno, Time, Price, ShareID.

I want to select the price of a given shareID wih the lowest Sno value. How do I achieve this using Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
Query q = session.
  createQuery("SELECT Price FROM PriceChange WHERE ShareID = ? ORDER BY Sno");
q.setFirstResult(1); 
q.setMaxResults(1);
```